# Cell Border appearig over the content in message box in Excel using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Im getting the following issue,

[image]

As you can see that, bottom border of the orange colored cells are coming over the message in the message box. How to fix this issue?

```
 private boolean createComments(int iCell,int iRow ,HashMap<String, String> hMap, XSSFSheet sheet, Row row, CellStyle style, String method){

          XSSFDrawing patr           = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

          boolean              errorcheck  = false;

          XSSFComment comment1    = null;

          String strComments      = null;


        if(hMap.containsKey(method) && iRow>0){

                 try{

                       strComments = hMap.get(method);

                       System.out.println("inside createComments--SSSSSSSSSSSSSS-- KKKKKKKKKKKKK");       

                       System.out.println("inside 555555555555555 createComments----JJJJJJJJJJ ");                 

                       comment1 = patr.createCellComment(new XSSFClientAnchor(500, 800, 1500, 1500, (short)iCell, iRow, (short) iCell + 3, iRow +3));                

                       comment1.setString(new XSSFRichTextString(strComments));

                       //row.getCell(iCell).setCellComment(comment1 );

                       row.getCell(iCell).setCellStyle(style);

                       errorcheck = true;

                 }catch(Exception e){

                  }

          }

          return errorcheck;

   }
```

Comment: Can you make it stop happening in Excel?

Comment: The screen-shot looks as if `Fill - Transparency` in `Format Comments - Colors and Lines` is set greater than 0. But this is nothing `apache poi` code could have done. So the problem (if it is one) is elsewhere.